# Oracle 10g - Determine the average of concurrent connections

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Is it possible to determine the average of concurrent connections on a 10g large database installation?

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more of a ServerFault question.

On a basic level, you could do this by regularly querying v$session to count the number of current sessions, store that number somewhere, and average it over time.

But there are already good utilities available to help with this. Look into [STATSPACK](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/tools.htm#29125). Then look at the scripts shown [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_display_oracle_sessions_per_minute.htm) to get you started.

Alternatively you could install a commercial monitoring application like [Spotlight on Oracle](http://www.quest.com/spotlight-on-oracle/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Oracle Enterprise Manager set up you can create a User Defined Metric which records SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION. Select Related Links -> User Defined Metrics to set up a new User Defined Metric. Once it collects some data you can get the data out in raw form or it will do some basic graphing for you. As a bonus you can also set up alerting if you want to be e-mailed when the metric reaches a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky bit is recording the connections.  Oracle doesn't do this by default, so if you haven't got anything in place then you won't have a historical record.

The easiest way to start recording connections is with Oracle's built in audit functionality.  It's as simple as

```
audit session
/
```

We can see the records of each connection in a view called `dba_audit_session`.

Now what?  The following query uses a Common Table Expression to generate a range of datetime values which span 8th July 2009 in five minute chunks.  The output of the CTE is joined to the audit view for that date; A count is calulated for each connection which spans a five minute increment.

```
with t as
     ( select to_date('08-JUL-2009') + ((level-1) * (300/86400)) as five_mins
       from dual connect by level <= 288)
select to_char(t.five_mins, 'HH24:MI') as five_mins
       , sum(case when t.five_mins between timestamp and logoff_time 
                  then 1 
                  else 0 end) as connections  
from t
     , dba_audit_session ssn  
where trunc(ssn.timestamp) = to_date('08-JUL-2009')
group by to_char(t.five_mins, 'HH24:MI')
order by t.five_mins
/
```

You can then use this query as the input into a query which calculates the average number of connections.

This is a fairly crude implementation: I choose five minute increments out of display considerations , but obviously the finer grained the increment the more accurate the measure.  Be warned: if you make the increments too fined grained and you have a lot of connections the resultant cross join will take a long time to run!